# When should a variable be used as random or fixed effect?

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model, multilevel-analysis, lme4-nlme

I am reading a paper that has collected crop yield data across multiple locations for multiple years. The paper uses yield as response and climate variables as predictors. Here is the equation:

[image]

where,

Y*it* = Yield for location *i* and year *t*

c*i* = location-specific intercept that controls for all location-specific time-invariant factors

γ*t* = linear trend coefficient that captures the effects of capital investment and techincal progress

Rest are climate variables and the error

What I need to know is

1) Is this a mixed effect models? In R's terminology, can the above equation be written as:

`mdl<-lm(log(yield) ~ site + year + Tmax + Tmin + SR + Rain)`

or

`mdl.lmer<-lmer(log(yield) ~ Tmax + Tmin + SR + Rain + (1|site) + (1|year))`

2) What is the difference between using `site` and `time` as fixed effect (in the first equation) and as random effect (in the second) and which one more correct to analyse the above dataset? or does it depend on the question I am asking?

**UPDATE:** I have the similar data. If I run the first model with site and year as fixed, it gives me a high R-squared while the second one with site as random gives me a low R-squared. Which model do I use? I always thought using site as random effect is the correct way because we account for the fact that points from same site will be correlated. Therefore the first equation is wrong but people have still used it in literature.

Thank you.

Comment: According to the equation, `Year` is definitely *not* a random effect. The `Site` can be either random of fixed, one cannot say from this equation. It is a modeling choice.

Comment: But the two equation has totally different R-squared. The first one gives a high R2 while the second one gives a low R2..how do you explain the difference? and which method to choose. I have edited the question to reflect this.

Comment: Again, if you want to assume that Year enters the model linearly as $\gamma t$ (as per the mathematical formula on top of your post), then you *cannot* treat it as a random effect.

Comment: Thank you. However, my question now is what is the difference between using a site as random or fixed effect. How are two models fundamentally different and which one is more correct.

Comment: There is a lot of info about that on this site, please search for random vs fixed effects. You can use either approach and both "account for the fact that points from same site will be correlated". In typical situations, most people prefer using a random effect. You might want to focus your question and copy-paste your code producing very different R-squared.